# How can I return IQueyrable DTO from Webapi Get so I can use Odata filters

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata, odp.net

I'm trying to use a Odata filters with ODP.net with Entity framework inside of web api project ASP.NET MVC 4.0 RC.  I want to return an IQueryable of OwnDTO . I get an internal 500 error without any details. I know there is an error generation bug with webapi RC, but I dont think that bug is my issue.

```
    Get http://localhost:51744/api/Owner  called using Fiddler




    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<OwnDTO> Get()        
    {            
        using (Entities context = new Entities())
        {
            var query = from item in context.Owners
                        select
                        new OwnDTO
                        {
                            Name = item.Name

                        };
            return query.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

//very simple for example

```
 public class OwnDTO
    {
        public string Name;
    }
```

I do not want to have use my Oracle EF generated classes (DAO) to return from my Get, but I know I can if I replace EntityObject with a more friendly interface.  If I return IEnumerable it works, but I want Odata filters.

---

Update incase someone wants a working example.. Automapper or simliar should be used in the linq and the context should injected.

---

```
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<OwnDTO> Get()        
    {            
        {
            var query = from item in Hack._EFContext.Owners
                        select
                        new OwnDTO
                        {
                            Name = item.Name

                        };
            return query.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

That works fine, but it looks like Odata is removed post RC. So I need to search down another path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It does work in RC** but perhaps not in RTM when it ships - not quite clear yet.

Your problem is that you are disposing your context since you are using a `using` block. So context get disposed before the data is retrieved.

So instead of `using` register your object for disposal at the end of request. Tugberk has a post [here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/disposing-resources-at-the-end-of-the-request-lifecycle-in-asp-net-web-api).

Comment: The [Queryable] attribute seems to have disappeared from RTM. Where is it?